# How to capture nativeElement for <ng-template> used in ngx-modal in Jasmine Unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using the `ngx-bootstrap` modal for displaying a modal form to the user. This modal takes a template which is defined in my component using

```
`<ng-template #template>.......</ng-template>`.
```

I wish to write a test spec in Jasmine for testing this modal template. I am unable to use DebugElement to capture the HTML elements defined inside the template because I feel it's hidden in DOM.

Moreover, after the modal is opened, `fixture.detectChanges()` also does not seem to bring the template to the DOM.

> What is the exact approach to do this?

Comment: P.S I do not want to use a different component for modal template and stick to <ng-template>

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to create separate component for the Modal and write test cases particularly for that. Your Page should have test cases just to open/close modal.

Modal Component test cases will have all tests which is having test cases of your business logic.

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to follow this approach of defining the modal template inside <ng-template>. Do you have any idea how to do this?